# Android Webview not showing full screen

Tags: java, android

Layout xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
    tools:context="com.laterpay.AddPaymentActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:text="Add Payment Method"
                    android:textColor="#003366"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:typeface="normal"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/bankSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_background"
                    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/titleTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/descriptionTextView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:text="This is."
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bankSpinner" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                    android:onClick="nextOnClick"
                    android:text="NEXT"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/descriptionTextView" />

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am trying to load an url using webview and would like to have it full screen. However, the webview is just not showing. How can I fix this? Been trying for few hours.

When I set the width and height to wrap_content, it is showing in the middle of the screen and not full screen. I would like to have it to show it full screen in the same activity.

Comment: after which control you want to place webview?

Answer (score 1):

@kylas: You should not put your `Webview` inside `ScrollView`. Because `Webview` itself provides  scrolling.

I just removed `ScrollView`. Now `Webview` showing in full screen.

Or if it's required to put `Webview` in `ScrollView` then there is three way.

1. You can provide fix height to your `Webview`.
2. You can use `ViewTreeObserver` to set `Webview` height dynamically.
3. You can set `android:fillViewport="true"` property in your `ScrollView`.

This might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use attribute `"match_constraint"` for `height` and `weight`. Which will give you something like this:

```
 <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

And your webview will be shown in full screen or the height of your parent layout.

And if you want to show on complete screen use your `scrollview` like this:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would need another scroll view in it?
WebView by nature contains scrollable view inside already, except if your entire view might be larger than the screen height.

If you are still keeping the scroll view, you might want to use this in your scroll view,

> android:fillViewport="true"

since scrolls view will not expand your linear layout naturally.